# Проблем с созданием массива jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

не могу понять как правильно записать данные в массив и вывести их.
Перебираю форму, хочу записать в массив значения,пример:

```
var tags_mas=[];
switch (data_type){
                    case 'tags':


                    $(this).parent().find(".valTags").each(function(){
                        textTags+=$(this).val()+",";
                    });
                    var mark='false';
                    var optional='true';
                    var mass_one={'value':textTags,'mark':mark,'optional':optional};
                    tags_mas.push(mass_one);
                    break;

                }

console.log("Массивы:"+tags_mas);
```

в консоле получаю

Массивы:[object Object]

Comment: неплохо было бы указать ожидаемый результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Товарищ, пользуйся консолью правильно!

```
console.log("Массивы:", tags_mas);
```

или

```
console.log("Массивы:" + JSON.stringify(tags_mas));
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пользоваться правильно!